# $dialog.messageBox equivalent

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dialog

With Angular I used to be able to do this

```
var title = 'title';
var messageBody = 'message';
var buttons = [{ result: 'ok', label: 'OK', cssClass: 'btn-primary' }];
$dialog.messageBox(title, messageBody, buttons).open();
```

But now, $dialog has been replaced with $modal.

What is the equivalent of the above in the new scheme?

Comment: It's pretty well described in the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), under the modal directive's chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using  $modal:

Example HTML:

```
<div>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">{{data.title}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        {{data.message}}
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Ok</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example JS:

```
var MyModalCtrl = function ($scope, $modal) {

    $scope.title = 'I'm a Modal';
    $scope.message = 'Hello World';
    $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/path/to/html',
        controller: MyModalInstanceCtrl,
        size: 'lg',
        resolve: {
        data: function () {
                return {title: $scope.title, message: $scope.message};
            }
        }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        console.log('Closed');
    });
};

var MyModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, data) {

    $scope.data = data;

    $scope.ok = function () {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };

};
```

The documentation for this can be found here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/